# How to Create Real-Time CRUD based web app using SocketIO

Tags: express, architecture, websocket, socket.io, crud

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266633/3259815).

What is suggested flow is good.

E.g.
Submit data to server: Use POST
Submit data from server to browser: Socket are best.

My question when to use sockets in CURD based web app.

Comment: I think you should post here your complete question, not just "look here, what to do next".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using Websockets for CRUD is always valid, but it depends on your specific app's needs.

If creation (C) and updates (U) are performed often and require real-time data exchange - i.e a stock trading app - you might want to use websockets for the C&U. I think google does that for google-docs, but I might be mistaken.

If reading data is time sensitive, you might use websockets for R&D (read and delete)...

Using websockets for the Read (R) is quite common for realtime updates (news, chat messages etc').

But usually, CRUD apps aren't time sensitive and mostly CRUD will be performed with an HTTP GET/POST request using a RESTful HTTP API.

As much as I love websockets, there are something that work great with simple HTTP ;-)